# Hive error An ORC ACID reader required to read ACID tables at

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

I created a Hive table stored as orc and then used Spark to register a data frame as temp table and then insert into the ORC Hive table from the registered temp table.

Now I can query the Hive-ORC table with Spark's SQL context, but I cannot query it from Hive at all.  When I try I get a stack trace that includes:

```
Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1470850820513_0032_2_00, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1470850820513_0032_2_00_000000, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at..
```

and

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.handleRecordReaderCreationException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.java:97)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.handleRecordReaderCreationException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.java:57)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(HadoopShimsSecure.java:266)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.<init>(HadoopShimsSecure.java:213)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileInputFormatShim.getRecordReader(HadoopShimsSecure.java:333)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat.getRecordReader(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:719)
        at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.lib.MRReaderMapred.setupOldRecordReader(MRReaderMapred.java:149)
        at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.lib.MRReaderMapred.setSplit(MRReaderMapred.java:80)
        at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.input.MRInput.initFromEventInternal(MRInput.java:650)
        at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.input.MRInput.initFromEvent(MRInput.java:621)
        at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.input.MRInputLegacy.checkAndAwaitRecordReaderInitialization(MRInputLegacy.java:145)
        at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.input.MRInputLegacy.init(MRInputLegacy.java:109)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.getMRInput(MapRecordProcessor.java:406)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.init(MapRecordProcessor.java:128)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:149)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileRecordReader.initNextRecordReader(HadoopShimsSecure.java:252)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: [Error 30021]: An ORC ACID reader required to read ACID tables
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.raiseAcidTablesMustBeReadWithAcidReaderException(OrcInputFormat.java:259)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.VectorizedOrcInputFormat$VectorizedOrcRecordReader.<init>(VectorizedOrcInputFormat.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.VectorizedOrcInputFormat.getRecordReader(VectorizedOrcInputFormat.java:176)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.createVectorizedReader(OrcInputFormat.java:1182)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat.getRecordReader(OrcInputFormat.java:1195)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveRecordReader.<init>(CombineHiveRecordReader.java:67)
        ... 31 more
```

Comment: what is your hive table definition ?